# Se puede pasar un set a un export function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cree un archivo donde almaceno todas las validaciones, dependiendo de cual necesito las instancio con import en los diferentes componentes de mi app, mi problema es que necesito setear el estado de una constante y al pasarla me señala que no es una función. Es posible pasar el setAcceptable y setearlo desde una función fuera de mi componente?

aquí llamo a la función:

```
   import { ValidateExtension } from '../../../../helpers/Helpers';      

   const toast = useRef(null);
   const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
   const [acceptable, setAcceptable] = useState(true)

   ValidateExtension(files, acceptable, setAcceptable, toast)
```

esta es la función alojada en otro componente:

```
export const ValidateExtension = (files, toast, setAcceptable, acceptable) => {
    //extensión archivos permitidos
    const accept = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'img', 'heic', 'bmp'];

    files.map(file => {
        if (acceptable) {
            //obtengo la extensión del archivo
            const fileEvaluation = file.name.split('.').pop();

            //Si la extensión del archivo NO se encuentra entre las permitidas...
            if (!accept.includes(fileEvaluation.toLowerCase())) {
                setAcceptable(false),
                    toast.current.clear(),
                    toast.current.show({
                        severity: 'warn',
                        summary: 'Tipo de archivo no permitido',
                        detail: 'Los formatos aceptados son: pdf, jpg, png, img, heic y bmp',
                        sticky: true,
                        closable: true,
                    });

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No puedes exportar el setState ya que este vive dentro del componente.

Comment: La única forma es pasarlo por parámetro